# Category Group Name Condition

Tags: categories

Is there a way to add a condition like {if results} or {if empty} when searching for a category in a channel entry?

```
{if a category 41 is selected display}Category Group Name: {categories show_group="41"}{category_name} {/categories}{/if}
```

I have a number of category groups in my channel. When displaying the selections I want to first show a heading (category group name) then the selected categories.  If nothing is selected I don't want anything to show.

I am testing: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/jco-entry-catcount

> {exp:jco_entry_catcount entry_id="{entry_id}" category_group_id="41":}
>       {if nbrcategories > 0}
>          Provincial Riding: {categories show_group="41"}{category_name} {/categories} 
>       {/if} {/exp:jco_entry_catcount}
>
> {exp:jco_entry_catcount entry_id="{entry_id}" category_group_id="39":}
>       {if nbrcategories > 0}
>          Federal Riding: {categories show_group="39"}{category_name} {/categories} 
>       {/if} {/exp:jco_entry_catcount}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use GWCODE CATEGORIES (http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation)

something like:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" group_id="41"}
######
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```